# Stop channels when ws not able to connect

Tags: multithreading, go, websocket, channel

I have the following code which works ok, the issue is that when the `socket.Connect()` **fails** to connect I want to stop the process, I’ve tried with the following code
but it’s not working, I.e. if the socket connect fails to connect the program still runs.
What I want to happen is that if the `connect` fails, the process **stops** and the **channe**…what am I missing here?

```
func run (appName string) (err error) {


        done = make(chan bool)
        defer close(done)


        serviceURL, e := GetContext().getServiceURL(appName)

        if e != nil {
            err = errors.New("process failed" + err.Error())
            LogDebug("Exiting %v func[err =%v]", methodName, err)
            return err
        }

        url := "wss://" + serviceURL + route


        socket := gowebsocket.New(url)
        addPass(&socket, user, pass)


        socket.OnConnectError = OnConnectErrorHandler
        socket.OnConnected = OnConnectedHandler
        socket.OnTextMessage = socketTextMessageHandler
        socket.OnDisconnected = OnDisconnectedHandler

        LogDebug("In %v func connecting to URL  %v", methodName, url)
        socket.Connect()

        jsonBytes, e := json.Marshal(payload)
        if e != nil {
            err = errors.New("build process failed" + e.Error())
            LogDebug("Exiting %v func[err =%v]", methodName, err)
            return err
        }

        jsonStr := string(jsonBytes)

        LogDebug("In %v Connecting to payload JSON is  %v", methodName, jsonStr)
        socket.SendText(jsonStr)

        <-done
        LogDebug("Exiting %v func[err =%v]", methodName, err)
        return err

    }


    func OnConnectErrorHandler(err error, socket gowebsocket.Socket) {
        methodName := "OnConnectErrorHandler"
        LogDebug("Starting %v parameters [err = %v , socket = %v]", methodName, err, socket)
        LogInfo("Disconnected from server ")
        done <- true
    }
```

The process should open one ws connection for process that runs about `60-90` sec (like execute npm install) and get the logs of the process via `web socke`t and when it finish , and of course handle the issue that could happen like network issue or some error running the process

Comment: what is the gowebsocket package you are using here? (looks like this one: https://github.com/sacOO7/GoWebsocket)

Comment: @Slabgorb - yes exactly, if you think it's related can you please provide a way how to replace it? as answer will be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, @Slabgorb is correct - if you look here (https://github.com/sacOO7/GoWebsocket/blob/master/gowebsocket.go#L87) you will see that the `OnConnectErrorHandler` is called synchronously during the execution of your call to `Connect()`. The `Connect()` function doesn't kick off a separate goroutine to handle the websocket until after the connection is fully established and the `OnConnected` callback has completed. So when you try to write to the unbuffered channel `done`, you are blocking the *same* goroutine that called into the `run()` function to begin with, and you deadlock yourself, because no goroutine will ever be able to read from the channel to unblock you.

So you could go with his solution and turn it into a buffered channel, and that will work, but my suggestion would be not to write to a channel for this sort of one-time flag behavior, but use `close` signaling instead. Define a channel for each condition you want to terminate `run()`, and in the appropriate websocket handler function, `close` the channel when that condition happens. At the bottom of `run()`, you can `select` on all the channels, and exit when the first one closes. It would look something like this:

```golang
package main

import "errors"

func run(appName string) (err error) {

    // first, define one channel per socket-closing-reason (DO NOT defer close these channels.)
    connectErrorChan := make(chan struct{})
    successDoneChan := make(chan struct{})
    surpriseDisconnectChan := make(chan struct{})

    // next, wrap calls to your handlers in a closure `https://gobyexample.com/closures`
    // that captures a reference to the channel you care about
    OnConnectErrorHandler := func(err error, socket gowebsocket.Socket) {
        MyOnConnectErrorHandler(connectErrorChan, err, socket)
    }
    OnDisconnectedHandler := func(err error, socket gowebsocket.Socket) {
        MyOnDisconectedHandler(surpriseDisconnectChan, err, socket)
    }
    // ... declare any other handlers that might close the connection here

    // Do your setup logic here
    // serviceURL, e := GetContext().getServiceURL(appName)
    // . . .
    // socket := gowebsocket.New(url)

    socket.OnConnectError = OnConnectErrorHandler
    socket.OnConnected = OnConnectedHandler
    socket.OnTextMessage = socketTextMessageHandler
    socket.OnDisconnected = OnDisconnectedHandler

    // Prepare and send your message here...
    // LogDebug("In %v func connecting to URL  %v", methodName, url)
    // . . .
    // socket.SendText(jsonStr)

    // now wait for one of your signalling channels to close.
    select { // this will block until one of the handlers signals an exit
    case <-connectError:
        err = errors.New("never connected  :( ")
    case <-successDone:
        socket.Close()
        LogDebug("mission accomplished! :) ")
    case <-surpriseDisconnect:
        err = errors.New("somebody cut the wires!  :O ")
    }

    if err != nil {
        LogDebug(err)
    }
    return err
}

// *Your* connect error handler will take an extra channel as a parameter
func MyOnConnectErrorHandler(done chan struct{}, err error, socket gowebsocket.Socket) {
    methodName := "OnConnectErrorHandler"
    LogDebug("Starting %v parameters [err = %v , socket = %v]", methodName, err, socket)
    LogInfo("Disconnected from server ")
    close(done) // signal we are done.
}
```

This has a few advantages:

1) You don't need to guess which callbacks happen in-process and which happen in background goroutines (and you don't have to make all your channels buffered 'just in case')

2) Selecting on the multiple channels lets you find out *why* you are exiting and maybe handle cleanup or logging differently.

Note 1: If you choose to use `close` signaling, you *have* to use different channels for each source in order to avoid race conditions that might cause a channel to get closed twice from different goroutines (e.g. a timeout happens just as you get back a response, and both handlers fire; the second handler to close the same channel causes a `panic`.) This is also why you don't want to `defer close` all the channel at the top of the function.

Note 2: Not directly relevant to your question, but -- you don't *need* to close every channel - once all the handles to it go out of scope, the channel will get garbage collected whether or not it has been closed.

Comment: Thanks, Regard `Note 1` , not sure that I fully got it, this is what we are getting `panic` when we have some issue, how you suggest to avoid it ?

Comment: Is this the panic you are getting? `panic: close of closed channel
` In Go, closing a closed channel will cause a panic. This is why I proposed making a different channel for each close reason: each of those channels should only be getting closed one time (i.e. your `OnDisconnect` handler should only be getting called once.) Find out which channels is getting closed more than once and why. #### Side Note: I copied your example and modified it to show where the channel closing would happen, but I realize now that I missed *how* the channels get passed to the callbacks. Will update this part...

Comment: @RaynD - I updated the example code to show how to make the channel references available to your callback handlers, using closures.

Comment: Thanks a lot! , Im providing a bounty since you already did a great work! currently im stuck with this code a lot, I think its related to the open source itself so I want to switch to `gorrila/ws`, it will be great if you can adjust the code to work with `gorrila/ws` as a sample `unit-test` like code which I can use as e2e to debug and understand better :).

Comment: I'm not sure i have time to write a full E2E example here, but if that's what you are looking for, I think you need to provide more context about the normal workflow of your real app: are you expecting to connect via websocket, send a message, get a response and exit? Or stay connected and serve requests? Do you really want you call a single method and have it block until the websocket connection closes? Etc.

Comment: The process is more simple as we need to open one ws connection for process that runs about 60-90 sec (like npm install) and get the logs of the process via web socket  and when it finish , and of course handle the issue that could happen like network issue or some error running the process.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, what is happening is the channel is blocking when you try to add something to it. Try initializing the `done` channel with a buffer (I used 1) like this:

`done = make(chan bool, 1)`

Comment: thanks, using your proposal cause to panic where there is a connection problem, is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Hi @RaynD - where is the panic coming from, the websocket package or your code?

Comment: HI,from the web socket

Comment: Sorry @raynd, would need a stack trace or something to be able to help you